# Postgres -Issue with inserting data into row - 'createdAt does not exist'

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

Hey I m trying to insert data into my product row

```
INSERT INTO products (title, category, quantity, price, createdAt) VALUES ('my     
bag', 'hipster', 2, 99.99, NOW());
```

However, I am getting this error: ERROR:  column "createdat" of relation "products" does not exist

Any ideas? Thanks!!

Comment: You created the column as `"createdAt"` so you must quote it forevermore. Quoted identifiers are case sensitive, the recommended practice with PostgreSQL is to use names like `created_at` instead.

Comment: Thanks! The error is gone now, but nothing is being added to my database..

Comment: Then you have a completely different problem and it is time to do a bit of debugging, there's no way anyone can tell you what's wrong with the limited information here.

Comment: actually now I tried it again (when i changed it to created_at) and get the same error: ERROR:  column "created_at" of relation "products" does not exist

Comment: Because you created the table with a `"createdAt"` column, not a `created_at` column.

Comment: how can I create it with the _  since its being created automatically (I don't create the createdAt column)

Comment: Then you have to refer to it as `"createdAt"` (with the quotes) in your INSERT. Presumably your Sequelize model would take care of this stuff for you so why are you writing an INSERT by hand?

Comment: I write it by hand because if I don't, Im getting an error saying I have to do that..Alao if I refer to it as "createdAt" it also tells me that the column doesn't exist :/

Comment: Well, go into `psql` from the command line and do a `\d products` to see what the table really looks like. I suspect you're not using Sequelize properly though.